# When a Task is completed, but from multiple plans in the same group

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-graph, microsoft-planner

as the title says,  I want to use the trigger When a Task is completed (power automate), but for multiple plans, that are in the same group.

I tried a workaround using schedule (every 10 min) listing first all my plans in the group, then listing all the tasks in each plan (for each loop) and then checking which task were completed in the last 10 mins. The problem with my approach is that I always get a timeout error, because it might be too much information for power automate.

My question then is, is there another way of doing this, maybe with MS Graph?

Comment: In the same boat. Did you ever find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be:

1. Create a flow for each of the plans, where the trigger is "when a task is completed" and the action is a call to another flow. See https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Trigger-a-flow-from-within-another-flow/td-p/567303 for suggestions on calling a flow from a given flow.
2. In this new child flow, carry out your desired action.

Comment: Although this approach would work, the goal would be to no have to manually create the flow every time but applying the flow to every plan in a group in order to avoid extra steps.